# How do I use Enums with JAXB?

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, enums, jaxb, unmarshalling

I would like to use JAXB to unmarshal an XML file into an object.
However, I want one of the fields in the XML file to be treated as a String Enum, because it should only be one of three possible values.
Right now, my object class looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="webApp")
public class WebApp {

  @XmlEnum(String.class)
  public enum AppTypes {
    Typeone, Typetwo, Typethree
  }

  @XmlElement(name="AppType")
  Enum<AppTypes> appType;

}
```

The XML file I'd like to unmarshal looks like this:

```
<webApp>
  <AppType>Typeone</AppType>
</webApp>
```

It doesn't work of course, but the stack trace is ridiculously long, and uninformative anyway, so I won't post it unless you want it.
Does you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using `AppTypes` instead of `Enum<AppTypes>`? And don't spare your uninformative stack trace, we love stack traces.

Comment: You, Dr., are a wizard.  Thank you, that worked well.  Fortunately, I no longer have a stack trace for you. Sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@lexicore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303810/lexicore) suggested, I should have been declaring appType as a AppTypes variable, not as an Enum.  It seems to work well now. :)